# mysql connection symfony + docker

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, docker

I'm using docker to develop a symfony project and I'm having a problem with mysql.
Here is my configuration in my .env symfony:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://bpp:bpp@127.0.0.1:3306/bdd
```

when i run the php bin / console command d: s: u --force the database is well updated.
By cons when I want to register a form I have a symfony connection error

[error sf4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqkdq.jpg)

Here is my config docker:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  apache:
    build: .docker/apache
    container_name: bpp_apache
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - .docker/config/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${SYMFONY_APP}:/home/wwwroot/bpp
    depends_on:
      - php
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: bpp_mysql
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/data/db:/var/lib/mysql
    command:
      - "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
      - "--lower_case_table_names=1"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  php:
    build: .docker/php
    container_name: bpp_php
    volumes:
      - ${SYMFONY_APP}:/home/wwwroot/bpp
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: bpp_phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Read this http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/su76/creating-apache-mysql-and-php-fpm-containers-for-a-web-application-with-docker-compose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the .env configuration for mysql url
from

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://bpp:bpp@127.0.0.1:3306/bdd
```

to

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://bpp:bpp@mysql:3306/bdd
```

The reason lies under docker itself. You are connecting two services:
PHP and MySql which are running on different IP address inside docker network. Every time you run the docker file, you are starting 3 containers:

1. Apache - IP Address 1
2. PHP - IP address 2
3. MySql - IP address 3

And MySql service is not on address 127.0.0.1. Leave this to the integrated DNS server.

Comment: with DATABASE_URL = mysql: // bpp: bpp @ mysql: 3306 / bdd it works but against the php bin / console command d: s: u --force does not work anymore

Comment: An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: H�te inconnu.

Comment: It seems to me that everything is fine with the URL. Try writing it again manually, maybe there is a non UTF character in the string.

Comment: Hmm try with "bpp_mysql" instead of "mysql" or just remove the container name from docker-file

Comment: same problem with bpp_mysql or remove container name

Comment: Remove the links - mysql from php container and it should work